# How to get a list of most popular articles in MODx?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

Is there any way to get a list of **most popular**(most viewed) articles in MODx? The documentation for getResources doesn't say anything in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the snippets [Page hit counter](http://modx.com/extras/package/pagehitcounter) and [Page Hit Counter results](http://modx.com/extras/package/pagehitcounterresults) to count visits and display them on your site.

Comment: Thank you. That was helpful.
I'm yet to try them. But its pretty much sure that they will work.

Comment: That worked but each time the page is visited the count increases by 3. What may be the reason for that? onWebPagePrerender system event firing multiple times? or the browser requesting the page multiple times?

Comment: Sorted it out. :)
It was Firefox requesting multiple times for a non-existent favicon.ico.
Edited .htaccess to ignore requests for favicon.ico and now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

There’s a dedicated solution for this now, using the “Extra” called “MostPopular”. https://modx.com/extras/package/mostpopular

You would track page views by calling the Snippet `[[!mpLogPageView]]` and subsequently when you want to list the most popular resources you call `[[mpResources]]` and pass the output to the getResources Snippet for templating.